# How to Update multiples row in a table with subquery in the where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2005.
I have a table like this:

```
Table Products

PkProduct   Price   DateChanged Active
1           4.99    2013-01-01  0
1           5.99    2014-01-01  1
2           10.50   2000-01-01  0
2           12.50   2002-01-01  0
2           14.50   2003-01-01  1
3           0.99    2000-01-01  1
4           0.99    2000-01-01  1
5           0.99    2000-01-01  1
```

The user can update the table from an application to add a new price for a product with a new date.

The user can also update multiple products at the same time (by selecting multiple product in the application at the same time) with a price and a date.

I want to **change the active column to 0 for the currently active product just before he add the new product** , so that I can set the new one to active (1)

```
example: 
PkProduct   Price   DateChanged Active
4       0.99    2000-01-01  0 <-- (was the one active before)
4       0.99    2015-01-01  1     (new one that he just add)
5       0.99    2000-01-01  0 <-- (was the one active before)
5       0.99    2015-01-01  1     (new one that he just add)
```

I also have a temporary table where I have split the string of pkProduct that contain for the example:

```
Temporary table #temptable
Pk
4
5
```

What I have right now is this:

```
UPDATE Products
SET Active = 0
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM Products
    WHERE Active = 1
    AND PkProduct IN (SELECT Pk FROM #temptable))
```

It seems the problem is the EXISTS, I tried with `PkProducts IN` AND a `LEFT JOIN`, but couldn't find how to get it right.

Thanks for your help! As always, I greatly appreciate =)

Comment: When/how do you do the `INSERT` for the new record?

Comment: You can use IN instead of exists -> update products set active = 0 where PkProduct in (select PkProduct from #tempTable) . It does not seem necessary to use products.active = 1

Comment: I do my insert like this `INSERT INTO Products (PkProduct, DateChanged, Price, Active) SELECT PkProduct, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 1.99,1 FROM Products --GETDATE, will be user's stuff later WHERE PkProduct IN (SELECT fk FROM #temptable) GROUP BY PkProduct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many subqueries.  This should be sufficient:

```
UPDATE Products
SET Active = 0
WHERE Active = 1 AND
      PkProduct IN (SELECT Pk FROM #temptable);
```

Comment: I would think that active = 1 is not necessary either.

Comment: Hmm! I tried your code and it work, Hourray! So the IN seems to do very well to select only the pk in my temporary table and update only them. 
I learn every day =) Thanks pal

Comment: @FernandoPabloEsposito Your telling that we can do without active = 1? Like resetting all active value for this PkProduct?

Comment: Because you only have 1 active value per product. The result is the same, all values per product in temp table   will be not active i.e. zero. The only one active will be the new value.

Answer (score 0):

For the `UPDATE` statement, you can do the following:

```
Update  P
Set     Active = 0
From    Products    P
Join    #tempTable  T   On  T.pk = P.pkProduct
Where   P.Active = 1
```

I'm assuming you're wanting to run this before you insert your new records.

Comment: I haven't try your code yet, The code of Gordon Linoff was working already but I think it must work too!